# drawInRect text alignment using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I am trying to put some text on top of an image that would be in the center of a CGRect which would be on top of that image. Here is a bit of code:

```
        let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 17
            )!
        let textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            NSTextAlignment: textAlignment
            ]

        myString.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
```

The problem is in the text alignment. When I write it like this I get an error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

When I set key and value types to [String : AnyObject] the compiler complains again:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSTextAlignment.Type' to expected dictionary key type 'String'

Which I understand. I researched this for like two hours and haven't found any up to date solution and not single one how cloud one write this using Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTextAlignment` isn't a valid key. Note how the other keys end in `Name`. See the docs for `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to see the list of valid keys.

Instead of `NSTextAlignment` you need to use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` which requires that you create an instance of `NSParagraphStyle`. That is where you set the `alignment` to `.Center`.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center
```

Answer (score 1):

The text alignment belongs to the paragraph style. Create a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` instance and pass it with key `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` to the attributes.

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .Center
let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
            ]
```